# Is it worth creating engines for simple projects?

Tags: architecture, software-engineering

I know, this question has already been answered in several places on the internet and the answer is NO.

But there are some points, I probably don't have the experience of half of you but I love C++ and I'm looking for more challenging projects, besides I always wanted to work with technologies like RT, DLSS etc out of curiosity.

Besides, I worry about a performance that I would probably lose with engines like Unreal, because let's say that for my project in mind it would be like killing a fly with a cannon.

Comment: It sounds like you've studied the advice that's out there, weighed it against your own needs and preferences, and found that you personally would like to try making your own engine anyway. That's a valid choice. You don't need anyone else to endorse it. Just go try it and see how things go. You can always put the custom engine project on hold and switch to an established engine if you find you hit a roadblock or the progress is much slower than you'd planned. And then you can come back to your custom tech again later and keep advancing it. So this needn't be an irrevocable all-or-nothing call.